# Python3 - A script with a function that reads a file

Tags: python-3.x, scripting

I have a function that reads a given file as an argument, I would like to make a script.

Here what I done :

```
import sys

def read_list_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as fobj :
        lines = fobj.read().splitlines()
    return lines

filenames = sys.argv[0]
if len(filenames) > 1 : read_list_from_file(filenames)
```

But nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens as in what should happen? One thing that the sys.argv[0] is the script name and sys.argv[1] is the first argument you pass to the script.

Also you have not added any print statements. The below with print gives output.

```
import sys

def read_list_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as fobj :
        lines = fobj.read().splitlines()
    return lines

filenames = sys.argv[1]
print(filenames)
print(len(filenames))
if len(filenames) > 1 : 
    print(read_list_from_file(filenames))
```